# using video.js with an HTML5 <audio> tag

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, html5-audio, video.js

I'm using video.js with an HTML5 `<audio>` tag and it works pretty well but there are some issues that I'm wondering if someone can offer some suggestions:

1. iOS safari doesn't show custom controls or the `.vjs-poster` background-image
2. `.vjs-poster` disappears on play and coincidently `.vjs-big-play-button` doesn't toggle play/pause on desktop browsers

Here's my HTML:

```
<script src='/path/to/video.js'/></script>
<audio id="videojs-audiojs" controls data-setup='{"height":"auto", "width":"auto"}'  
        poster="/img/01.png" class=" video-js vjs-default-skin"><!--preload="none"-->
        <source src='https://dhol01ptzx2vt.cloudfront.net/uploads/4/4/v1/01BorntoDie.m4a' type="audio/mp4">
        <source src='http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg' type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```